# Let $M$ be a maximal ideal of $R$, then $M+(x)$ is a maximal ideal of $R[x]$.

Tags: ring-theory

Let $M$ be a maximal ideal of $R$, then $M+(x)$ is a maximal ideal of $R[x]$.

(I forget where the exercise come from, so I'm not sure whether $R$ has an identity.)

My attempt is as follows:

Let $N$ be an ideal in $R[x]$ such that $M+(x) \subseteq N \subseteq R[x]$. Let $N' = \{a \in R : a = f(0) \mbox{ for some } f \in N\}$, then $N'$ is an ideal in $R$ such that $M \subseteq N' \subseteq R$.

*Let $a, b \in N'$, then $a = f(0)$ and $b = g(0)$ for some $f, g \in N$. Let $r \in R (\subseteq R[x])$. Since $N$ is an ideal in $R[x]$, we have $f-g, rf$, and $fr$ in N. It follows from
$$ a-b = (f-g)(0), ra = (rf)(0), \mbox{ and } ar = (fr)(0) $$
that $a-b, ra$, and $ar$ in $N'$.
Let $a \in M$, then $a+x \in M+(x) \subseteq N$. So we obtain that $a \in N'$.*

Since $M$ is a maximal ideal in $R$, we have $N' = M$ or $N' = R$.

Note that $N \subseteq N'+(x)$. If $N' = M$, then $N = M+(x)$.

But I cannot prove the another case. Can somebody help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Well if $N' = R$, then it still spells that $M$ is maximal since there is no proper ideals that contains $M$.

Answer (score 1):

> I forget where the exercise come from, so I'm not sure whether  has an identity.

Almost certainly identity is assumed, because if not it is not even immediately clear what $R[x]$ means. (If it means $\{\sum r_i x^i\mid r_i\in R \text{ (finite support)}\}$, then how can one even be sure if $x\in R[x]$?)

> Let $N' = \{a \in R : a = f(0) \mbox{ for some } f \in N\}$, then $N'$ is an ideal in $R$ such that $M \subseteq N' \subseteq R$.

Uhh... aren't you already almost done right after this step?  By maximality of $M$, either $N'=R$, whence $N'+(x)=R+(x)=R[x]$ or else $N'=M$ whence $N'+(x)=M+(x)$.

---

What you did is equivalent to what most people would do: compute $R[x]/(M+(x))$.

By the second isomorphism theorem, $R[x]/(M+(x))\cong \frac{R[x]/(x)}{(M+(x))/(x)}\cong\frac{R}{M}$, so that $M$ is maximal in $R$ iff $M+(x)$ is maximal in $R[x]$.

Comment: I still don't understand that how to infer $N = R[x]$ (if $N' = R$)?

Comment: @EnyaHsu Isn't it obvious that $R+(x)=R+xR[x]=R[x]$?